# translating a older swift line of code about recording a mic signal to swift 4.2

Tags: swift, audio-recording

I got this in a older version of my app

```
var recSession: AVAudioSession!
recSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
try recSession.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playAndRecord)
```

How should I translate the last line into swift 4.2.

setCategory is deprecated, but what is the alternative?

Comment: Solved with OOPer his comment below.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
try recSession.setCategory(.playAndRecord, mode: .default)
```

Seems [Apple is recommending to set category and mode at the same time](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession/1616583-setcategory?language=objc).

> Note
>
> Instead of setting your category and mode properties independently,
>   it's recommended that you set them at the same time using the
>   [`setCategory:mode:options:error:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession/1771734-setcategory?language=objc) method.

`AVAudioSession`'s `mode` defaults to `AVAudioSession.Mode.default`, so if your app does not change it, the code above should work.

Comment: Thank you so much. Build succeeded. This was the last issue.